# Multiple domains in one root with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have two domains, pointing at a single hosted root;

firstdomainname.com and seconddomain.com will point to one root.

like

mymaindomain.com

mymaindomain.com/first-domain/

mymaindomain.com/second-domain/

my existing htaccess code is (not working)

---

```
#two domains served from one root..
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} firstdomainname.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/first-domain
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ first-domain/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} seconddomain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^second-domain
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ second-domain/$1 [L]
```

---

It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will fix your problem, but you're missing a forward slash in `!^two` should be `!^/two`

Answer (score 0):

Use following rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^firstdomainname\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/first-domain/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /first-domain/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^seconddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/second-domain/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /second-domain/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Can you replace `[L]` with `[R,L]` and then check what URL shows up in your browser. Then you can see whether redirected URL is valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

I use the names "subsite1" and "subsite2" instead of "firstdomain" and "seconddomain" for semantic clarity.

These rewrite rules below will load the correct content and enforce your subsite domains.

```
# Force subsite domain for subsite directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?subsite1/?(.*)$
RewriteRule .* http://subsite1.com/%1 [R=302,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?subsite2/?(.*)$
RewriteRule .* http://subsite2.com/%1 [R=302,QSA]

# Load appropriate content
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subsite1\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?(.*)$
RewriteRule .* /subsite1/%1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subsite2\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?(.*)$
RewriteRule .* /subsite2/%1 [L]
```

These rules will, unlike yours, prevent redundant URLs like "subsite1.com/subsite1" because the rewrites in the first set of rules are not conditional on the domain.

Once you've tested this be sure to change the R=302's in the first set of rules to R=301's.